# How to explain array[value - 'a']

Tags: c++, vector

What does this mean and how does it work?

```
if (intVec[v.at(i) - 'a'] == 0)
```

Comment: Poor man's method to convert `a`, `b`, `c`, etc. into `0`, `1`, `2`, etc.

Comment: 'a' is a 97 in ascii code...

Comment: What part don't you understand? The `if (...)` part? The `intVec[v.at(i) - 'a'] == 0` part? The `v.at(i)  - 'a'` part? The `v.at()` part? The `'a'` part? The `-` part?

Comment: yes i know 'a''s ascii code is 97 but why we need to minus (-) it ?if (intVec[v.at(i) - 'a'] == 0)
        {
          intVec[v.at(i) - 'a'] = 1;
        }
      else{
        v.at(i) = '@';
      }

Comment: @TMcKeown:  Some ASCII characters are better known in hexadecimal.  For example 'a' is 0x61 and the capital 'A' is 0x41.  The difference between the two is 0x20, which is conveniently a bit.

Comment: You presented code with no context. There is no way to know for sure why we need to subtract `'a'`. We can tell you what it does, and we can guess why, but there's no way to know for sure without seeing more code, or even better, a discussion of the underlying algorithm behind the code.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `v` contains characters `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'` etc.,

```
v.at(i) - 'a'
```

subtracts `'a'` from those characters.

```
'a' - 'a' == 0
'b' - 'a' == 1
'c' - 'a' == 2
```

and so on.

Comment: And the reason why you would do this is: it lets you store data values corresponding to an range of keys relatively efficiently, compared to other methods. Other options include a vector of size 256 and accessing the slots corresponding to character's raw values (e.g. `char c = 'a'; intVec[c] = 1;`) but if you only care about the letters a-z, 200+ slots are unused and wasted. A map is another option, but it also has overhead.